# How to view contents of a heap block given the block address WinDbg

Tags: windows, memory, windbg, heap-memory

I was recently looking through this paper(https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec09/tech/full_papers/ratanaworabhan.pdf) in which the software "scans heap objects
to identify valid x86 code sequences." For the past couple of weeks I have been trying to get this to work.

So far I have gotten far enough such that I can print the rtlallocateheap parameters and print its return value. RTLAllocateheap returns the pointer of the heap block that has been allocated. However, using this pointer how can I identify whether or not the block at this location is a valid x86 code sequence?

I have attached an image of WinDbg to show what I have so far[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `u <address>` to disassemble:

```
Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 001a0000
0:003> u 001a0000
001a0000 90              nop
001a0001 90              nop
001a0002 90              nop
001a0003 90              nop
001a0004 31c0            xor     eax,eax
001a0006 90              nop
001a0007 90              nop
001a0008 90              nop
```

Unluckily, many bytes will result in valid opcodes. To me, the question is more: how can you tell whether those opcodes are harmless or harmful.

Only if you see question marks like here, you could tell that this is not valid code.

```
0:003> u 5d0000
005d0000 32e3            xor     ah,bl
005d0002 388895280001    cmp     byte ptr [eax+1002895h],cl
005d0008 ee              out     dx,al
005d0009 ff              ???
005d000a ee              out     dx,al
005d000b ff02            inc     dword ptr [edx]
```